# MySQL: How to retrieve all rows with a duplicate field, matching a LIKE on a certain field in any matched row

Tags: mysql

I have a database containing about 300,000 rows of product information.
I need to retrieve rows with **duplicate UPCs** (COUNT(upc) > 1), where **at least one** of the results' descriptions matches a certain string ("Reed", for example.)

For example, the following rows would all be selected (desc, upc pairs)

```
Deer D7394    62226173
Reed R2536    62226173
Deer D7217    62226173
```

but none of

```
Deer D0173    62278389
Deer D7289    62278389
Deer D9272    62278389
```

Here is the query I'm working with:

```
SELECT a.desc, a.upc, a.sku, a.short_description 
FROM inventory a 
JOIN 
    (SELECT upc, desc 
    FROM inventory 
    GROUP BY upc 
    HAVING COUNT(upc) > 1) b 
ON a.upc = b.upc 
WHERE ((a.desc LIKE '%Reed%') OR (b.desc LIKE '%Reed%'))
AND a.upc != '' 
AND a.upc != 0 
ORDER BY upc;
```

I am relatively new to MySQL, but this seems like it should work. However, **some** results are failing to return the non-matching row (i.e. Reed R2536 will be returned, but not Deer D7394).

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brian's `group_concat` method will work, when the number of duplicates is small, but it will fail silently when it's not. You'll never know; you'll just be missing rows that should be present.

What you want to do is select all of the UPCs where at least one description matches (and for which duplicates exist), and then, from that list, select all rows matching each of those UPCs.

If you group all items by UPC, then you can annotate each one with a count, and flag whether any of the descriptions matched:

```
SELECT upc, COUNT(*) c, MAX(`desc` LIKE '%Reed%') desc_matches
FROM inventory
GROUP BY upc
```

(This takes advantage of the fact that boolean operators, like `LIKE`, actually return `0` for false and `1` for true. Taking the maximum of that column tells you whether any row matched)

Then you can filter that list based on your criteria, to get just the UPCs you are interested in:

```
SELECT upc, COUNT(*) c, MAX(`desc` LIKE '%Reed%') desc_matches
FROM inventory
GROUP BY upc
HAVING desc_matches = 1 AND c > 1
```

Once you have that list, you want to see all products that match any of those UPCs. You can do that with a simple (not OUTER) join:

```
SELECT a.desc, a.upc, a.sku, a.short_description 
FROM inventory a 
JOIN 
    ( SELECT upc, COUNT(*) c, MAX(`desc` LIKE '%Reed%') desc_matches
      FROM inventory
      GROUP BY upc
      HAVING desc_matches = 1 AND c > 1
    ) b USING (upc)
```

Comment: I just tested both of these - am I missing something, or do they only satisfy the text match criteria? I'm interested in this approach, but it also needs to check for duplicates.

Comment: You're right -- I missed that when I read it. I've re-worked the query to filter those items out.

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea you could use `LIKE` that way, and this does appear to catch a few rows with a lot of duplicates that the other query missed.  I've updated the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way to do this, assuming that you don't have TOO many duplicate records would be:

```
select * from inventory i
  join (
         SELECT upc 
           FROM inventory 
            GROUP BY upc 
            HAVING COUNT(upc) > 1
              and group_concat(`desc`) like '%reed%') as available_upc 
          on available_upc.upc = i.upc
```

This assumes that your tables looks something like:

```
CREATE TABLE inventory(
  sku CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `desc` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  upc CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  short_description CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sku)
);

insert into inventory values ('D7394','Deer','62226173','Small Deer');
insert into inventory values ('R2536','Reed','62226173','Small Reed');
insert into inventory values ('D7217','Deer','62226173','Large Deer');


insert into inventory values ('D0173','Deer','62278389','Small Deer');
insert into inventory values ('D7289','Deer','62278389','Small Reed');
insert into inventory values ('D9272','Deer','62278389','Large Deer');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without testing, but try:

```
SELECT a.desc, a.upc, a.sku, a.short_description 
FROM inventory a 
OUTER RIGHT JOIN 
    (SELECT upc
    FROM inventory 
    GROUP BY upc 
    HAVING COUNT(upc) > 1) b 
ON a.upc = b.upc 
WHERE ((a.desc LIKE '%Reed%') OR (b.desc LIKE '%Reed%'))
AND a.upc != '' 
AND a.upc != 0 
ORDER BY upc;
```

The key is the `OUTER RIGHT JOIN`.  Please see the article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Also, you only need to return the upc from the inner `SELECT` query.

Comment: Thanks! However, I get "unknown field b.desc" when I remove desc from the inner `SELECT`.
Also, a syntax error prompted me to specify a type of outer join, so I'm currently running `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Unfortunately, it's taking too long to be practical in this situation (>300,000 rows in the table).